# Underscore's _.keys function only returning numermic indexes of keys not the value of keys in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, underscore.js

I am trying to get the value of the key to set autocomplete values for my drop downs. The user will enter "LOAN" in the "#currentSelectedLevel" field and jQuery will populate all of the ".episysFieldName" fields with the keys from the loansFields.

```
if($("#currentSelectedLevel").val()=="LOAN"){                
    $(".levelFieldName").autocomplete('option', 'source', _.keys(loanFields));}


var loanFields = [

  {"BALANCE": "MONEY"},
  {"OPENDATE": "DATE"},
  {"CLOSEDATE": "DATE"}
];
```

When I do an alert I just get the indexes of the values. [0,1,2]. I need it to return "BALANCE", "OPENDATE", "CLOSEDATE".

```
alert( _.keys(loanFields));
```

I have the jQuery code working fine when I just use strings in the array.

Note:  The reason I am starting to use objects/key value pairs is because in the future I need to know the type of the field and possibly other properties. I believe my issue is how I am structuring the object within the array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should pass a regular object to `_.keys`. `0`, `1`, `2` are the array keys, the indices of the array.

Comment: `_.flatten(_.map(loanFields, _.keys))` should return `["BALANCE", "OPENDATE", "CLOSEDATE"]`. You can also use the [`_.chain`](http://underscorejs.org/#chain) method if the code snippet is hard to read: `_.chain(loanFields).map(loanFields, _.keys).flatten().value()`

Comment: Native js : `loanFields.map(function(obj){ for(var k in obj) return k; })` (IE 9+) or you can use underscore `_.map() `.

Comment: Native js: `loanFields.map(x => Object.keys(x)[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by doing it another way. Hope my answer helps someone else.

I created an array of objects.

```
var loanFields = [

  {name: "BALANCE", 
   type: "MONEY"
  },
  {name: "OPENDATE", 
   type: "DATE"
  },
  {name: "CLOSEDATE", 
   type: "DATE"
  }
];
```

Then used the _.propertyOf function to get the name properties and assign them to an array and return that to jQuery to be assigned as the auto complete values.

```
function getFieldNamesFromArray(fieldNameArray){
  var fieldNames = [];

  // use underscore.js to get just name property value
  for (var i = 0; i < fieldNameArray.length; i++) {
      fieldNames.push(_.propertyOf(fieldNameArray[i])('name'));
  }
  return fieldNames;

}
```

And the following to assign it to the dropdown.

```
if($("#currentSelectedLevel").val()=="LOAN"){                
              $(".levelFieldName").autocomplete('option', 'source', getFieldNamesFromArray(loanFields));}
```